# SQL Server CTE and recursion example

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

I never use CTE with recursion. I was just reading an article on it. This article shows employee info with the help of Sql server CTE and recursion. It is basically showing employees and their manager info. I am not able to understand how this query works. Here is the query:

```
WITH
  cteReports (EmpID, FirstName, LastName, MgrID, EmpLevel)
  AS
  (
    SELECT EmployeeID, FirstName, LastName, ManagerID, 1
    FROM Employees
    WHERE ManagerID IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT e.EmployeeID, e.FirstName, e.LastName, e.ManagerID,
      r.EmpLevel + 1
    FROM Employees e
      INNER JOIN cteReports r
        ON e.ManagerID = r.EmpID
  )
SELECT
  FirstName + ' ' + LastName AS FullName,
  EmpLevel,
  (SELECT FirstName + ' ' + LastName FROM Employees
    WHERE EmployeeID = cteReports.MgrID) AS Manager
FROM cteReports
ORDER BY EmpLevel, MgrID
```

Here I am posting about how the output is showing:
[image]

I just need to know how it is showing manager first and then his subordinate in a loop.
I guess the first sql statement fires only once and that returns all employee ids.

And the second query repeatedly fires, querying the database on which employee exists with the current manager id.

Please explain how the sql statement executes in an internal loop and also tell me the sql execution order. Thanks.

### MY 2nd phase of question

```
;WITH Numbers AS
(
    SELECT n = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT n + 1
    FROM Numbers
    WHERE n+1 <= 10
)
SELECT n
FROM Numbers
```

Q 1) how is the value of N is getting incremented? if the value is assigned to N every time then N value can be incremented but only the first time N value was initialized.

Q 2) CTE and recursion of employee relations:

The moment I add two managers and add a few more employees under the second manager is where the problem starts.

I want to display the first manager detail and in the next rows only those employee details that relate to the subordinate of that manager.

### Suppose

```
ID     Name      MgrID    Level
---    ----      ------   -----
1      Keith      NULL     1
2      Josh       1        2
3      Robin      1        2
4      Raja       2        3
5      Tridip     NULL     1
6      Arijit     5        2
7      Amit       5        2
8      Dev        6        3
```

I want to display the results in such way with CTE expressions. Please tell me what to modify in my sql which I gave here in order to pull manager-employee relations. Thanks.

### I want the output to be like this:

```
ID          Name   MgrID       nLevel      Family
----------- ------ ----------- ----------- --------------------
1           Keith  NULL        1           1
3           Robin  1           2           1
2           Josh   1           2           1
4           Raja   2           3           1
5           Tridip NULL        1           2
7           Amit   5           2           2
6           Arijit 5           2           2
8           Dev    6           3           2
```

Is this possible...?

Comment: https://learnsql.com/blog/sql-recursive-cte/

Answer (score 226, accepted):

I haven't tested your code, just tried to help you understand how it operates in comment;

```
WITH
  cteReports (EmpID, FirstName, LastName, MgrID, EmpLevel)
  AS
  (
-->>>>>>>>>>Block 1>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
-- In a rCTE, this block is called an [Anchor]
-- The query finds all root nodes as described by WHERE ManagerID IS NULL
    SELECT EmployeeID, FirstName, LastName, ManagerID, 1
    FROM Employees
    WHERE ManagerID IS NULL
-->>>>>>>>>>Block 1>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
    UNION ALL
-->>>>>>>>>>Block 2>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>    
-- This is the recursive expression of the rCTE
-- On the first "execution" it will query data in [Employees],
-- relative to the [Anchor] above.
-- This will produce a resultset, we will call it R{1} and it is JOINed to [Employees]
-- as defined by the hierarchy
-- Subsequent "executions" of this block will reference R{n-1}
    SELECT e.EmployeeID, e.FirstName, e.LastName, e.ManagerID,
      r.EmpLevel + 1
    FROM Employees e
      INNER JOIN cteReports r
        ON e.ManagerID = r.EmpID
-->>>>>>>>>>Block 2>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
  )
SELECT
  FirstName + ' ' + LastName AS FullName,
  EmpLevel,
  (SELECT FirstName + ' ' + LastName FROM Employees
    WHERE EmployeeID = cteReports.MgrID) AS Manager
FROM cteReports
ORDER BY EmpLevel, MgrID
```

The simplest example of a recursive `CTE` I can think of to illustrate its operation is;

```
;WITH Numbers AS
(
    SELECT n = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT n + 1
    FROM Numbers
    WHERE n+1 <= 10
)
SELECT n
FROM Numbers
```

**Q 1) how value of N is getting incremented. if value is assign to N every time then N value can be incremented but only first time N value was initialize**.

`A1:` In this case, `N` is not a variable. `N` is an alias. It is the equivalent of `SELECT 1 AS N`. It is a syntax of personal preference. There are 2 main methods of aliasing columns in a `CTE` in `T-SQL`. I've included the analog of a simple `CTE` in `Excel` to try and illustrate in a more familiar way what is happening.

```
--  Outside
;WITH CTE (MyColName) AS
(
    SELECT 1
)
-- Inside
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT 1 AS MyColName
    -- Or
    SELECT MyColName = 1  
    -- Etc...
)
```

[image: Excel_CTE]

**Q 2) now here about CTE and recursion of employee relation
the moment i add two manager and add few more employee under second manager then problem start.
i want to display first manager detail and in the next rows only those employee details will come those who are subordinate of that manager**

`A2:`

Does this code answer your question?

```
--------------------------------------------
-- Synthesise table with non-recursive CTE
--------------------------------------------
;WITH Employee (ID, Name, MgrID) AS 
(
    SELECT 1,      'Keith',      NULL   UNION ALL
    SELECT 2,      'Josh',       1      UNION ALL
    SELECT 3,      'Robin',      1      UNION ALL
    SELECT 4,      'Raja',       2      UNION ALL
    SELECT 5,      'Tridip',     NULL   UNION ALL
    SELECT 6,      'Arijit',     5      UNION ALL
    SELECT 7,      'Amit',       5      UNION ALL
    SELECT 8,      'Dev',        6   
)
--------------------------------------------
-- Recursive CTE - Chained to the above CTE
--------------------------------------------
,Hierarchy AS
(
    --  Anchor
    SELECT   ID
            ,Name
            ,MgrID
            ,nLevel = 1
            ,Family = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Name)
    FROM Employee
    WHERE MgrID IS NULL

    UNION ALL
    --  Recursive query
    SELECT   E.ID
            ,E.Name
            ,E.MgrID
            ,H.nLevel+1
            ,Family
    FROM Employee   E
    JOIN Hierarchy  H ON E.MgrID = H.ID
)
SELECT *
FROM Hierarchy
ORDER BY Family, nLevel
```

### Another one sql with tree structure

```
SELECT ID,space(nLevel+
                    (CASE WHEN nLevel > 1 THEN nLevel ELSE 0 END)
                )+Name
FROM Hierarchy
ORDER BY Family, nLevel
```

Comment: the CTE recursive query does not return result the way i want. i want to display first manager name and then display all his subordinate again display second manager name and then display all his subordinate. i want the output should be in this fashion. if possible please update ur query. thanks

Comment: [Family] column added. Check now.

Comment: here i give the output the way i want to display result. please check and tell me is it possible...if yes then do the necessary modification in ur sql. thanks for ur effort.

Comment: why is the ';' before the WITH statement? ";WITH" Thanks

Comment: A CTE will not run without the previous statement(s) being terminated by a semi-colon so it has become a habit :)

Comment: @SiKni8 - the link seems to be dead

Comment: I actually solved it with some documentation from MSoft. Thank you for looking into it though.

Comment: Heads-up that in PostgreSQL 9 you need to declare the cte as recursive, eg `with recursive foo as (...)`

Answer (score 12):

Would like to outline a brief semantic parallel to an already correct answer.

In 'simple' terms, a recursive CTE can be semantically defined as the following parts:

1: The CTE query. Also known as ANCHOR.

2: The recursive CTE query on the CTE in (1) with UNION ALL (or UNION or EXCEPT or INTERSECT) so the ultimate result is accordingly returned.

3: The corner/termination condition. Which is by default when there are no more rows/tuples returned by the recursive query.

A short example that will make the picture clear:

```
;WITH SupplierChain_CTE(supplier_id, supplier_name, supplies_to, level)
AS
(
SELECT S.supplier_id, S.supplier_name, S.supplies_to, 0 as level
FROM Supplier S
WHERE supplies_to = -1    -- Return the roots where a supplier supplies to no other supplier directly

UNION ALL

-- The recursive CTE query on the SupplierChain_CTE
SELECT S.supplier_id, S.supplier_name, S.supplies_to, level + 1
FROM Supplier S
INNER JOIN SupplierChain_CTE SC
ON S.supplies_to = SC.supplier_id
)
-- Use the CTE to get all suppliers in a supply chain with levels
SELECT * FROM SupplierChain_CTE
```

Explanation:
The first CTE query returns the base suppliers (like leaves) who do not supply to any other supplier directly (-1)

The recursive query in the first iteration gets all the suppliers who supply to the suppliers returned by the ANCHOR.
This process continues till the condition returns tuples.

UNION ALL returns all the tuples over the total recursive calls.

Another good example can be found [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx).

PS: For a recursive CTE to work, the relations must have a hierarchical (recursive) condition to work on. Ex: elementId = elementParentId.. you get the point.

Answer (score 12):

The execution process is really confusing with recursive CTE, I found the best answer at https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx and the abstract of the CTE execution process is as below.

The semantics of the recursive execution is as follows:

1. Split the CTE expression into anchor and recursive members.
2. Run the anchor member(s) creating the first invocation or base result set (T0).
3. Run the recursive member(s) with Ti as an input and Ti+1 as an output.
4. Repeat step 3 until an empty set is returned.
5. Return the result set. This is a UNION ALL of T0 to Tn.

Answer (score -7):

```
    --DROP TABLE #Employee
    CREATE TABLE #Employee(EmpId BIGINT IDENTITY,EmpName VARCHAR(25),Designation VARCHAR(25),ManagerID BIGINT)

    INSERT INTO #Employee VALUES('M11M','Manager',NULL)
    INSERT INTO #Employee VALUES('P11P','Manager',NULL)

    INSERT INTO #Employee VALUES('AA','Clerk',1)
    INSERT INTO #Employee VALUES('AB','Assistant',1)
    INSERT INTO #Employee VALUES('ZC','Supervisor',2)
    INSERT INTO #Employee VALUES('ZD','Security',2)


    SELECT * FROM #Employee (NOLOCK)

    ;
    WITH Emp_CTE 
    AS
    (
        SELECT EmpId,EmpName,Designation, ManagerID
              ,CASE WHEN ManagerID IS NULL THEN EmpId ELSE ManagerID END ManagerID_N
        FROM #Employee  
    )
    select EmpId,EmpName,Designation, ManagerID
    FROM Emp_CTE
    order BY ManagerID_N, EmpId
```

Comment: This is a code-only answer that doesn't even answer the question, since there's no *recursive* CTE in it.