# Generic recursive sql query

Tags: sql, database, oracle

If there is a table which as 2 columns, ParentId and ChildId and there could be multiple levels, as table below

```
ParentId    ChildId
   -1             1
   -1             2
    1             3
    3             4
    4             5
```

If the child has no parent it is indicated by -1.

Now if I need the parent at the topmost level for say 5 , then its parent is 4 whos parent is 3 whos parent is 1. So  1 is the answer as its parent = -1.

I went through the discussion in [Sql server CTE and recursion example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14274942/sql-server-cte-and-recursion-example), seemed complex.

From googling I got to know that we can use WITH AS and UNION to achieve this, can any one shed some light on a generic sql that can get this result ?

thanks

Nohsib

Comment: What exactly is the output that you want the SQL statement to return?  Do you want the entire hierarchy?  Or just the highest-level parent?  If you want the hierarchy, in what format do you want it?  Multiple rows? A concatenated formatted string? Something else?

Comment: @ Justin : Just the id of the highest-level parent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select connect_by_root(ChildId) as id
from t
where ChildId = 5
start with ParentId = -1
connect by ParentId = prior ChildId
```

[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b86d8/1)

Comment: Thankyou Egor. This works fine from the sql developer but through the application that uses the below code it shoots out the exception with SQLCODE=-313, SQLSTATE=07004

Comment: Properties props = new Properties();
  props.setProperty("user", username);
  props.setProperty("password", password);
  Connection conn = null;
  conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, props);
  Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
   statement .executeQuery(
    "select connect_by_root(ChildId) from t where ChildId = 5 start with ParentId = -1  connect by ParentId = prior ChildId");

Comment: @Nohsib - Try adding alias for column (see my updated answer).

Comment: @ Egor : Still no luck :( same exception

Comment: @Nohsib - 1) Could you successfully execute `select dummy from dual`?  2) Is `t` real name of your table?  3) Try to prefix schema name to table name: `schema.t`

Comment: @Nohsib - 4) Is your database really Oracle DBMS, not DB2 ?

Comment: @ Egor : Issue was with my database the query works 'as is' in your solution. It works both on oracle and db2.  Accepting it. Thankyou.