# Get List of all columns of all tables and Reference table follwled by reference Key of table

Tags: sql, sql-server, treeview

Hello I have 50 Tables in Sql server.

All the tables are in join.

***For Ex.***

**Country Table**

```
PKCountryID
Name
```

**State Table**

```
PKStateID
FKCountryID
Name
```

**City Table**

```
PKCityID
FKStateID
Name
```

**Employee Table**

```
PKID
FIrstName
LastName
FKCityID
```

So i want all the columns of all tables. For that i write below Fiddle.

[Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cbf33/5)

This will give me result like

**COLUMN_NAME**

```
PKEmployeeID
Name
FKCityID
```

But I want result like this.

**COLUMN_NAME**

```
 PKEmployeeID
 Name
-FKCityID
     PKCityID
     Name
    -FKStateID
          PKStateID
          Name
         -FKCountryID
               PKCountryID
               Name
  PKCityID
  Name
 -FKStateID
      PKStateID
      Name
     -FKCountryID
            PKCountryID
            Name

  PKStateID
  Name
 -FKCountryID
       PKCountryID
       Name

  PKCountryID
  Name
```

Comment: OP usually mean Original Post(er) on stack overflow, do you mean to say Output?

Comment: @Tanner yes i mean output.

Comment: So do you want your results in a treeview or tabular output? The desired result and tag indicate treeview, but with the fiddle you expect some SQL to be written?

Comment: I want it in any format. but if it will in tree view that will great help for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try recursive common table expression. Something like:

```
;
WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   c.name AS column_name ,
                       -- t.object_id AS tableid ,
                        0 AS treelevel
               FROM     sys.tables AS t
                        INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID
               WHERE    t.object_id = 754101727
               UNION ALL
               SELECT   c.name ,-- + ' ' + f.referenced_column_name AS column_name ,
                        --t.object_id AS tableid ,
                        treelevel + 1
               FROM     ( SELECT    f.name AS foreign_key_name ,
                                    OBJECT_NAME(f.parent_object_id) AS table_name ,
                                    COL_NAME(fc.parent_object_id,
                                             fc.parent_column_id) AS constraint_column_name ,
                                    OBJECT_NAME(f.referenced_object_id) AS referenced_object ,
                                    COL_NAME(fc.referenced_object_id,
                                             fc.referenced_column_id) AS referenced_column_name ,
                                    is_disabled ,
                                    delete_referential_action_desc ,
                                    update_referential_action_desc ,
                                    f.referenced_object_id AS parent_object_id
                          FROM      sys.foreign_keys AS f
                                    INNER JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns AS fc ON f.object_id = fc.constraint_object_id
                        ) f
                        JOIN cte ON cte.column_name = f.constraint_column_name
                        JOIN sys.tables AS t ON t.object_id = f.parent_object_id
                        INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID

                        --IN ORDER TO STOP LOOP AT SPECIFIC LEVEL YOU NEED:
                        WHERE treelevel < 2

             )
    SELECT  
           --IN ORDER TO REMOVE DOUBLINGS ADD DISTINCT
            DISTINCT *
    FROM    cte
    ORDER BY treelevel, tableid
```

How recursive works you can find here: [Sql server CTE and recursion example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14274942/sql-server-cte-and-recursion-example)

Comment: This will goes into loop query can not execute

Comment: It is, if you have loop of references between tables, so will be your tree

Comment: updated the answer, for tables with many references it will take some time to process