# SQL parent child n-th level recursion

Tags: sql, oracle, hibernate

I'm using oracle database with hibernate. 
I have a EMPLOYEE table, with a self link back to itself on manager. Something like this:

```
create table employee(
id number(14) not null,
username varchar(100) not null unique,
manager number(14),

constraint employee_pk primary key (id),
constraint employee_manager_fk foreign key (manager) references employee (id)
);
```

Currently, I can select a employee and its direct child with:

```
select e2.*
from employee e2,
(select e.* from employee e where e.username='abc') e1 
where e2.manager = e1.id

union 

select e.* from employee e where e.username='abc'
```

I want to run a query where when given one employee username I can selected all it's child employees down to the n-th level. How do I do it in a SQL statement?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sql server CTE and recursion example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14274942/sql-server-cte-and-recursion-example)

Comment: hmmm... it's related, but since even the answer is different, I believe it's not a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's what `connect by` is for:

```
select *
from employee 
where level <= 5
connect by prior id = .manager
start with username = 'abc'
```

Note that `level` starts counting from 1 at the row identified with `start with`. It is not the "overal" hierarchy level of the tree.

More details in the manual: 
 http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/queries003.htm#SQLRF52332

Answer (score 0):

```
select e1.*
from employee e2
left outer join 
employee e1  on e1.id= e2.manager 
where e2.username='abc'
union 
select e.* from employee e where e.username='abc'
```

Comment: That is not a recursive query.