# How do I parse a field with multiple words and look each word up in a different table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, string-concatenation

I have a table `RxDir` that contains columns `RxNum` and `Dir`.  `Dir` is comprised of user-entered text that is a combination of quick codes and free text.  The quick codes are stored in a table called `SCodes` under column `SCode`.

I need to create an expanded result of the directions when given `RxNum`.  So if `Dir` contains

```
LYLAS BUT OMG YOU HAVE VD & BEANS
```

Then I need to have the results interpreted as

```
LOVE YOU LIKE A SISTER BUT OH MY GOODNESS YOU HAVE VIENNA DOGS & BEANS
```

(Assuming that the obvious initials are stored in `SCodes` and the full words are not).

Comment: Have you tried anything? I would look at a recursive CTE.

Comment: I have not; wasn't sure where to begin.  When I needed the info in the past, I've been able to just settle for the "un-expanded" view of the directions.  Been researching but hadn't came across recursive CTE.  I will check it out.

Comment: this is a pretty good example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14274942/sql-server-cte-and-recursion-example

Comment: Where will you get the meaning of LYLAS

Comment: Thanks Holmes.  wewesthemenace, sorry- LYLAS is in the SCodes table, the meaning is in the ExTxt column.

Comment: Do you ever have a situation of composite phrases?  Where you have two or more words in the SCODE column?

Comment: Great question, Brad; sorry I didn't mention this originally.  No, I don't believe so.  Lots of random characters across the values, but no spaces that I can see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing you want is a string splitter. Here is the [**`DelimitedSplit8K`**](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/), one of the fastest splitter there is.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DelimitedSplit8K](
    @pString VARCHAR(8000), @pDelimiter CHAR(1)
)
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
RETURN
WITH E1(N) AS (
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
)
,E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b)
,E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b)
,cteTally(N) AS(
    SELECT TOP (ISNULL(DATALENGTH(@pString), 0)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
)
,cteStart(N1) AS(
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
    SELECT t.N+1 FROM cteTally t WHERE SUBSTRING(@pString, t.N, 1) = @pDelimiter
),
cteLen(N1, L1) AS(
SELECT 
    s.N1,
    ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@pDelimiter, @pString, s.N1),0) - s.N1, 8000)
FROM cteStart s
)
SELECT 
    ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY l.N1),
    Item       = SUBSTRING(@pString, l.N1, l.L1)
FROM cteLen l
```

Now, what you want is to split each `Dir` with `' '` as the delimiter. Using your sample data and the function above

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.DelimitedSplit8K('LYLAS BUT OMG YOU HAVE VD & BEANS', ' ')
```

The result is:

```
ItemNumber  Item
----------- ----------
1          LYLAS
2          BUT
3          OMG
4          YOU
5          HAVE
6          VD
7          &
8          BEANS
```

Using the above result, you can now do a `LEFT JOIN` on `SCodes` to get the meaning or `ExTxt` of each `Item`. Then you concatenate the `ExTxt` back to achieve the desired result.

Your **FINAL QUERY** will be:

```
SELECT
    rd.RxNum,
    rd.Dir,
    Result = 
        STUFF((
            SELECT ' ' + ISNULL(sc.ExTxt, x.Item)
            FROM dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(rd.Dir, ' ' ) x
            LEFT JOIN SCodes sc
                ON sc.SCode = x.Item
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),        
        1, 1, '')
FROM RxDir rd
```

**RESULT**

```
| RxNum |                               Dir |                                                                Result |
|-------|-----------------------------------|-----------------------------------------------------------------------|
|     1 | LYLAS BUT OMG YOU HAVE VD & BEANS | LOVE YOU LIKE A SISTER BUT OH MY GOODNESS YOU HAVE VIENA DOGS & BEANS |
```

*Note: See this [**article**](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings) by Aaron Bertrand for other string splitters.*

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cf62b/1/0)