# Recursive CTE - Returning odd and even records

Tags: sql, common-table-expression

Pretty stuck and hoping someone can help

I need to use a common table expression to display (select) all the odd   Employee_ID rows first and then all the even Employee_ID rows from the employee table.

This is what I have written so far, definitely not correct. Would be great if someone can help.

```
WITH MYCTE (Employee_ID)
AS (
    SELECT 1 AS odd
    FROM Employee

    UNION ALL

    SELECT odd + 1
    FROM Employee
    WHERE odd < 10
    )
SELECT *
FROM MYCTE
ORDER BY CASE 
        WHEN odd % 2 = 1
            THEN 0
        ELSE 1
        END
    ,odd ASC
```

Comment: You can't specify order in a CTE! Just add ORDER BY to the main query. `SELECT * FROM Employee_Table ORDER BY Employee_ID & 1 DESC, Employee_ID`

Comment: The *only* thing that controls the order of results is the `ORDER BY` clause on the final/outermost query.

Comment: what dbms vendor is it for please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is to add a `ORDER BY` similar to the one below:

`order by case when odd%2 = 1 then 0 else 1 end, odd asc`

Here is a sample [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/accc72/2).

Added to your code, this would look like:

```
With MYCTE(Employee_ID)
As 
(
Select 1 as odd
From Employee_Table 

UNION ALL

Select odd + 1
From Employee_Table
)
Select *
From MYCTE
ORDER BY CASE 
             WHEN Employee_ID%2 = 1 
                 THEN 0 
             ELSE 1 
         END, Employee_ID ASC
```

After closer inspection I noticed that your Recursive CTE wasn't built correctly, which is why you were getting constant errors.

I re-wrote your CTE and now it should work as expected. Also check out [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/27f3d/12) to see the results.

```
with mycte (empID, employee_name, reportsTo)
as (
   select 
      employee_id
      , employee_nm
      , reportsTo
    from employee
    where reportsto = 0

    union all

    select
      e.employee_id
      , e.employee_nm
      , e.reportsTo
    from employee e
      inner join mycte mc on e.reportsTo = mc.empID        
  )
select *
from mycte
order by case
            when empID%2 = 1
              then 0
            else 1
          end, empID ASC
```

Comment: Thanks. When I run the query, it says odd is an invalid column name. Any idea?

Comment: @ShiyuZhu Retry now. I changed the column name from `odd` to `Employee_ID` in the `ORDER BY` (it was my mistake).

Comment: do you mean like this?

Comment: With MYCTE(Employee_ID)
As 
(
Select 1 as odd
From Employee_Table 

UNION ALL

Select odd + 1
From Employee_Table
)
Select *
From MYCTE
ORDER BY CASE 
             WHEN Employee_ID%2 = 1 
                 THEN 0 
             ELSE 1 
         END, Employee_ID ASC

Comment: @ShiyuZhu Yes, like that (just like my answer is now)

Comment: sorry, I'm probably being stupid and its still returning invalid column odd. I have updated my question to reflect what I am running in SQLfiddle

Comment: @ShiyuZhu Look at my answer. The `ORDER BY` is not made on `odd` but on `Employee_ID`. Why? Because when you defined your `CTE` you specified `WITH MYCTE(Employee_ID)`, which means that the output of the `CTE` will be the `Employee_ID` column and **not** the column called `odd`. If you want to order by `odd` column, then you'll have to remove the `Employee_ID` column from your `CTE` definition, like this `WITH MyCTE() AS ... `

Comment: Yep, that does makes sense but my query is still falling, which I have no idea why. It is still giving the same error on SQL fiddle.  I have updated the Order by columnname to employeeID. My other question is that, in the final results, will that be 2 columns? 1 column with all the employeeids and another odd column, where it will have either a 0 or 1, indicating its a even or odd?

Comment: @ShiyuZhu Can you share the link with the SQLFiddle you're using?

Comment: @ShiyuZhu Take a look here and let us know if it works for you: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/27f3d/1 (You really don't need a CTE to get the result in this form).

Comment: Totally understand that I don't have to use CTE. but this is a university lecture question Im trying to answer and we have to use recursive CTE which is super annoying!

Comment: @ShiyuZhu Here it is: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/27f3d/12 Your CTE wasn't formed correctly. I had to re-write it for you.

Comment: @ShiyuZhu And, for more examples and details check out this [awesome answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14275097/1266737).

Comment: Thank you so much. One question though， why did you have to put a where for ReportsTo in the first select?

Comment: @ShiyuZhu It is called the `anchor` (anchor condition) in a Recursive CTE. It identifies the `root` nodes. Take a look at the answer I linked in my above comment, it has all the details you need.

Comment: actually don't worry. I think i understand it now. Is it because, Richard doesn't report to anyone, and so he is like the superboss? and so we use him as an anchor for the recursive bit?

Comment: @ShiyuZhu Exactly, he is the achor for the rest of the execution. He is the `top of the hierarchy` a.k.a. the `"top boss"`, nobody is above him :)

Comment: totally makes sense now. I think I just clicked. Thank you so much for your help :D :D :D

Comment: @ShiyuZhu You're welcome. Don't forget to mark the correct answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select t.* from
(
Select row_number() over (order by (select 1)) as sno, * From Employee_Table
) as t
order by case when sno%1=1 then 1 else 2 end, sno
```

Answer (score 0):

Why use a CTE at all, it's not required to meet the sorting criteria.

```
select * from employees
order by (employee_id % 2) DESC, employee_id
```

nb: This assumes % is used for modulo in your dbms

e.g. 3 % 2 = 1, 4 % 2 = 0

Comment: He doesn't want to filter the employees based on even or odd id values. He wants them all returned and ordered (read the question again).

Comment: (yes, but the balance is simple, and now shown) still do not see the need for a CTE

Comment: Could be, but we don't know the scope of the change that OP wants to make. Maybe this is a simplified version of a `CTE`. I would also recommend your solution if this is the only thing that OP wants to do, and if he's starting from scratch. Also, take a look that `employee_id` is actually the name of the output of the `CTE`.

Comment: even if the CTE is simplified, it is only the final ORDER BY clause which sets the output sequence, doesn't matter how complex the CTE is, or if it exists at all

Comment: Exactly, which is why emphasis is on the `ORDER BY` and not on what set of queries returns the underlying result set.

Answer (score 0):

I used this code to make series of 1 to 99 odd numbers using recursive CTEs

```
WITH oddnumber AS 
(
  SELECT 1 AS MYNUMBER 
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT 1+(MYNUMBER) FROM ODDNUMBER 
  WHERE MYNUMBER<100 
)
SELECT MYNUMBER 
FROM oddnumber
WHERE MYNUMBER%2=1
```