# SQL query to get multihierarchy items

Tags: sql, hierarchy, multi-level

in my SQL Table i have following data

```
ID  Level   Description     Code    MasterID
1   1       Cars            AD0       NULL
2   1       Trucks          JF1       NULL
3   1       Items           YU2       NULL
4   2       New Cars        AS3        1
5   2       Used Cars       TG4        1
6   2       Car parts       UJ5        1
7   2       New trucks      OL6        2
8   2       Used trucks     PL7        2
9   2       Truck parts     KJL8       2
10  2       Factory stuff   UY9        3
11  2       Custom stuff    RT10       3
12  3       Toyota          6YH11      4
13  3       BMW             9OKH12     4
14  3       VW              13         5
15  3       Tiers Type I    J14        6
16  3       Tiers Type II   J15        6
17  3       Tiers Type III  ADS16      9
18  3       Seats           SA17       6
19  3       Doors           UU18       6
20  3       Lights          9OL19      6
21  4       Left light      GH20       20
22  4       Right light     H21        20
23  4       Left door       JHJ22      19
24  4       Michelin        UY23       16
25  4       Vredestein      GTF24      17
26  4       Dunlop          25         15
```

My achievement is to get all hierarchy data for each single item. For Exmaple, the outpu should look like as following

```
ID  Level   Description   Code   MasterId1   Description1     MasterId2   Description2    MasterId3    Description3

24   4       Michelin     UY23       16      Tiers Type II       6         Car Parts           1        Cars
.
.
19   3       Doors        UU18       6       Car Parts           1          Cars               NULL      NULL
.
.
10   2       Factory Stuff UY9       3       Items               NULL     NULL                 NULL     NULL
.
.
3    1        Items        NULL      NULL     NULL               NULL     NULL                 NULL     NULL
.
.
```

If somebody can help or give an advise how to achieve this?

Comment: Can you show us what you've done so far?

Comment: Generally a [CTE would do the trick in this scenario](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14274942/sql-server-cte-and-recursion-example). I suggest you start from here and also take a look at `UNPIVOT`, then dynamic SQL and then think of a way to combine all of them together. But all of this depends on the RDBMS you're using.

Comment: is there a maximum number of Levels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not dynamic but it could be pretty easily.

Using a recursive cte you can get the hierarchy for the entire table and self join a few times to get the table structure you want.

```
;WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT *, ID AS [RootID], 1 AS [MasterLevel] FROM Table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t1.*, cte.[RootID], cte.[MasterLevel] + 1  FROM Table1 t1
    JOIN cte ON t1.ID = cte.MasterID  
)
SELECT  r.ID, r.[Level], r.[Description], r.[Code],
        m1.ID AS MasterId1, m1.[Description] AS Description1, 
        m2.ID AS MasterId2, m1.[Description] AS Description2,
        m3.ID AS MasterId3, m1.[Description] AS Description3
FROM    cte r
        LEFT JOIN cte m1 ON m1.[RootID] = r.[RootID] AND m1.MasterLevel = 2
        LEFT JOIN cte m2 ON m2.[RootID] = r.[RootID] AND m2.MasterLevel = 3
        LEFT JOIN cte m3 ON m3.[RootID] = r.[RootID] AND m3.MasterLevel = 4
WHERE   r.MasterLevel = 1
ORDER BY r.RootID DESC, r.MasterLevel
```

This would build a dynamic sql to get master and desciption fields based on the maximum `Level` value.  or you could define how many levels you want to see by changing the `@MaxLevel`

```
DECLARE @Sql VARCHAR(MAX) = '',
        @SelectSql VARCHAR(MAX) = '',
        @JoinSql VARCHAR(MAX) = '',
        @MaxLevel INT,
        @idx INT = 1

SET @MaxLevel = (SELECT MAX([Level]) FROM Table1)
WHILE @idx < @MaxLevel
BEGIN
    SET @SelectSql = @SelectSql + REPLACE(', m<index>.ID AS MasterId<index>, m<index>.[Description] AS Description<index> ', '<index>', @idx)
    SET @JoinSql = @JoinSql + REPLACE(' LEFT JOIN cte m<index> ON m<index>.[RootID] = r.[RootID] AND m<index>.MasterLevel = <index> ', '<index>', @idx)
    SET @idx = @idx + 1
END        
SET @Sql = '
    ;WITH cte AS 
    (
        SELECT *, ID AS [RootID], 0 AS [MasterLevel] FROM Table1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT t1.*, cte.[RootID], cte.[MasterLevel] + 1  FROM Table1 t1
        JOIN cte ON t1.ID = cte.MasterID  
    )
    SELECT  r.ID, r.[Level], r.[Description], r.[Code]' + @SelectSql
    + 'FROM cte r ' + @JoinSql
    + 'WHERE    r.MasterLevel = 0
    ORDER BY r.RootID DESC, r.MasterLevel'

EXEC(@Sql)
```