# How to approach to find parents for child in sql server 2012?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

I've a table like this:

[image]

If I'm given a single or a list of menuID, I need to find the all the parents for all the menuID. For Example if I'm given MenuID as 1601120013, I need to find the following.

[image]

I'm a newbie to sql, I'm not even sure how to approach this kind of scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `Recursive CTE`

```
WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT menuld, 
                menutitle, 
                parentmenuld 
         FROM   Yourtable 
         WHERE  menuld = 1601120013 
         UNION ALL 
         SELECT t.menuld, 
                t.menutitle, 
                t.parentmenuld 
         FROM   cte c 
                INNER JOIN Yourtable t 
                        ON t.menuld = c.parentmenuld) 
SELECT * 
FROM   cte
```

- [**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/591f35/1)

Comment: Perfect. But I would like to understand more about CTE, I googled for it, can you please recommend something? Thanks.

Comment: Check this question [Sql server CTE and recursion example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14274942/sql-server-cte-and-recursion-example)