# Distinct on 3 columns when I have 7

Tags: sql, db2

I want an output like this table using db2...

```
NR  TAG1    TAG2    someData1   someData2
=========================================
1   Class1  2015    11665456     862187687
1   Class1  2014    33254665     86221187687
1   Class1  2013    55557321     8687687787
2   Class2  2015    21654765     86822117687
2   Class2  2014    57658776     8632187687
2   Class2  2013    54878575     8682127687
```

now I trying but failing to write an SQL Code
to have a Distinct on the first 3 rows.

When I try to get all data with (*) I get 865 records.

When I only take the first 3 rows and ignore the rest with distinct I get 808 records.

But I dont know how to show the rest of the data.

Comment: And evidently you don't know how to show the data to us in your question, either.  That being said, can you clue us in on your table structure and data?

Comment: Use `GROUP BY` to group the first 3 columns

Comment: But I cant group here, becouse I want to show all data and remove duplicates only in the first three columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume you want to remove duplicates by considering only first three COLUMNS and display the result. If my understanding is wrong, please explain further.

```
with cte as 
    (select *, row_number() over(partition by NR, TAG1, TAG2 order by NR, TAG1, TAG2) as row_num from Table_name)
    select * from cte where row_num=1
```

Comment: I want exactly what you explained remove duplicates by considering only first three COLUMNS. But not (*) rather only NR, TAG1, TAG2, someData1, someData2 becouse there is a lot more in that table and what cte stand for?

Comment: Look up Common table expression for understanding of CTE. If you do not want all columns replace the * with only columns you need and you are good to go !

Comment: For starters, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14274942/sql-server-cte-and-recursion-example

Comment: Does this works on db2? becouse I´m now lost. In the from clause I have to write my table name?

Comment: Sorry I missed FROM TABLENAME in the query, I have edited it now. And yes it works in DB2