# Write a hierarchical query in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `tbl` in SQL Server. Here's what the data in that table looks like:

[image]

In `SystemPartLevel` I save the value of parent (`SystemPartID`)

I have to show these records in a treeview in C# like this:

[image]

I need a SQL query that will show all children of 'A' or 'B'.

I want to see all child of every node.

For example for 'A' =

```
{A1, A2, A1-1, A1-2, A1-1-1}
```

or for A1 =

```
{A1-1, A1-2, A1-1-1}
```

How can I write this query?

Thanks

Comment: If you are looking for any node related to `A` then you could simply query `select *
from tbl
where left(tbl.SystemPartName, 1) = 'A'` and if you are looking for all nodes below `A1` then you could query `select *
from tbl
where left(tbl.SystemPartName, 2) = 'A1'`. Alternatively, you could pass the search-term to the query as use `select *
from tbl
where tbl.SystemPartName like @SearchTerm + "%"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sql server CTE and recursion example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14274942/sql-server-cte-and-recursion-example)

Comment: Essentially this requires string aggregation, which is simple in postgres but a little tricky in SQL server. Check out [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273238/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-sql-server) for how to do this in SQL Server.

Comment: @Ralph no this is incorrect because this data is sample and i cant use left() statement.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: This is not the correct way to store hierarchial data in sql server. The correct way is for each item to have a parent id (that would be null for root items). Store your data like this and use a recursive cte to get the hierarchy