# SQL practice troubles for beginner TYT

Tags: sql

i've just study SQL for a month and there is many things I'm still cannot get a hold of. Can anyone help me, plz provide the results with some explaination, I need to understand it for future uses. I only list things that I cannot understand.

- List the ID of the managers and the total number of employees reporting to each of them. Display the result in descending order of the total number of employees

I can do:

```
SELECT employeeNumber
FROM employees
WHERE jobTitle LIKE '%Manager%'
UNION
SELECT employeeNumber, COUNT(*)
FROM employees
WHERE reportsTo 'WHICH CONDITION?'
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Can someone fill in after 'reportTo', I cant find a condition that's working TYT

- Display all offices and their counts in each country
  I think this mean showing a table with every country and count total number of offices in that country

I can do:

```
SELECT country, COUNT(*)
FROM offices
GROUP BY country
UNION
SELECT country, officeCode
FROM offices
```

But the results is not as expected

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14274942/sql-server-cte-and-recursion-example

Answer (score 0):

```
select
reportsTo,
COUNT(employeeNumber) as numberOfEmployees
from employees
group by reportsTo
```

Will give you a count of employeeNumbers that report to that reportsTo.
This will not give you the managers where nobody is reporting to, so to do that you would have to make a JOIN:

```
SELECT
a.employeeNumber AS managerNumber,
COUNT(b.employeeNumber) AS numberOfEmployees
FROM employees AS a
LEFT JOIN employees AS b on (b.reportsTo=a.employeeNumber)
WHERE a.jobTitle LIKE '%Manager%'
GROUP BY a.employeeNumber
```

Comment: Tks a lot, you're my savior, my sql hero, it works perfectly

Comment: @Stellar in that case, may I suggest you mark this answer as correct...