# How to use result of first query in second query where condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to select two tables data, One is `PackageData` and another is `PackageDataDetails`. Here is PackageData is Parent table and PackageDataDetails is child table.

See below code:

```
SELECT 
    PD.Id, PD.MemberId, PD.Merchant, PD.Weight, PD.Remarks
FROM 
    [dbo].[PackageData] PD
INNER JOIN 
    Account A ON A.MemberId = PD.MemberId
INNER JOIN 
    Users U ON U.Id = A.UserId AND (@UserId IS NULL OR U.Id = @UserId)
WHERE 
    (@Status IS NULL OR @Status = '' OR  PD.SystemStatus = @Status)
    AND (@Id IS NULL OR PD.Id = @Id)
ORDER BY 
    MD.Id
    OFFSET @PageSize * (@PageNo+1 - 1) ROWS  
    FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY 
OPTION (RECOMPILE);

SELECT 
    PDD.Id, PDD.PackageDataId, PDD.Description, PDD.Quantity, PDD.Status
FROM 
    [dbo].[PackageDataDetails] PDD
INNER JOIN 
    [dbo].[PackageData] PD ON PD.Id = PDD.PackageDataId
WHERE 
    PDD.PackageDataId IN ({PD.Id of Above Select query})
```

This code block is written in a stored procedure. Here, I didn't want to rewrite the first query in where a condition of the second query.

I have to use this stored procedure in one API response to do things in one DB call only. Please share your idea to resolve this issue.

Comment: Use a recursive CTE.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14274942/sql-server-cte-and-recursion-example

Comment: put first query result into temp table and simply join in second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert your first query data in table variable and then fetch the id from table variable in second query.Something like below.

Code:

```
 Declare @tblData TABLE
    ( 
        Id          Int,
        MemberId                    Int,
        Merchant    NVARCHAR(Max),
        Weight  NVARCHAR(Max),
        Remarks               Nvarchar(Max)

    );

   Insert Into @tblData
(
    Id,
    MemberId,
    Merchant,
    Weight,
    Remarks
)

SELECT PD.Id ,PD.MemberId, PD.Merchant,PD.Weight,PD.Remarks
FROM [dbo].[PackageData] PD
INNER JOIN Account A ON A.MemberId = PD.MemberId
INNER JOIN Users U ON U.Id = A.UserId AND (@UserId IS NULL OR U.Id = @UserId)
WHERE (@Status IS NULL OR @Status = '' OR  PD.SystemStatus = @Status)
AND (@Id IS NULL OR PD.Id = @Id)
ORDER BY MD.Id
OFFSET @PageSize * (@PageNo+1 - 1) ROWS  FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY OPTION (RECOMPILE);

SELECT PDD.Id, PDD.PackageDataId, PDD.Description, PDD.Quantity, PDD.Status
FROM [dbo].[PackageDataDetails] PDD
INNER JOIN [dbo].[PackageData] PD ON PD.Id = PDD.PackageDataId
WHERE PDD.PackageDataId IN (select Id from @tblData )
```

Comment: Yes, this way will works now for me. but here we have to create temp table, please provide if you have any other way for this without temp table. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please try below query.

First Query

```
SELECT 
    PD.Id ,PD.MemberId, PD.Merchant,PD.Weight,PD.Remarks
    INTO #temp 
    FROM [dbo].[PackageData] PD
    INNER JOIN Account A ON A.MemberId = PD.MemberId
    INNER JOIN Users U ON U.Id = A.UserId AND (@UserId IS NULL OR U.Id = @UserId)
    WHERE (@Status IS NULL OR @Status = '' OR  PD.SystemStatus = @Status)
    AND (@Id IS NULL OR PD.Id = @Id)
    ORDER BY MD.Id
    OFFSET @PageSize * (@PageNo+1 - 1) ROWS  FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```

get output first query

```
 SELECT * FROM #temp
```

Second query with the first query result.

```
SELECT 
     PDD.Id, PDD.PackageDataId, PDD.Description, PDD.Quantity, PDD.Status
FROM [dbo].[PackageDataDetails] PDD
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[PackageData] PD ON PD.Id = PDD.PackageDataId
    WHERE PDD.PackageDataId IN (SELECT PD.Id FROM #temp)

DROP TABLE #temp
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a CTE(Common Table Expression):

i.e:

```
    ;with CTE1 as (
 select 1 as Col1,
 2 as Col2,
 3 as Col3
), CTE2 as (
select 1 as Col1,
        5 as Col2,
        6 as Col3
)select * from CTE1 where CTE1.Col1 IN (select Col1 from CTE2)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the first query to feed the second, wrap the first in a CTE and refer to in running the second query:

```
;WITH PackageDataFiltered AS
(
    SELECT PD.Id ,PD.MemberId, PD.Merchant,PD.Weight,PD.Remarks
    FROM [dbo].[PackageData] PD
    INNER JOIN Account A ON A.MemberId = PD.MemberId
    INNER JOIN Users U ON U.Id = A.UserId AND (@UserId IS NULL OR U.Id = @UserId)
    WHERE (@Status IS NULL OR @Status = '' OR  PD.SystemStatus = @Status)
    AND (@Id IS NULL OR PD.Id = @Id)
    ORDER BY MD.Id
    OFFSET @PageSize * (@PageNo+1 - 1) ROWS  FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY 
)
SELECT PDD.Id, PDD.PackageDataId, PDD.Description, PDD.Quantity, PDD.Status
-- You can refer to fields from the CTE here too
-- like select the PDF.Merchant or PDF.Remarks
FROM [dbo].[PackageDataDetails] PDD
INNER JOIN [dbo].[PackageData] PD ON PD.Id = PDD.PackageDataId
INNER JOIN PackageDataFiltered PDF ON PDF.Id = PDD.PackageDataId
```

Comment: possibly it will work, I need both select query results, but in this case, I can only select One table, means only either CTE result selected or use it in where the condition of a second query.

So for this, I can use the answer of @Techgeeks1.