# Grouping Contact details into separate columns in SQL based on its type

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, string-aggregation

I have multiple phone number, multiple email address, multiple fax address in a contact column.  I need a query to get the result like below

```
Contact Id |Phone                 |Email                       |Fax
1          |Phone1, Phone2, Phone3|Email1, Email2,Email3,Email4|Fax1, Fax2
2          |Phone1, Phone2        |Email1, Email2,Email3       |Fax1, Fax2
```

My Input is like

```
Value    MeansOfCommunicationDescription    ContactId
email1@port2.com    Email    2
www.1_port2.com    Web Site    2
Test Insert    Fax    2
Test Insert    Web Site    2
Test Insert    Web Site    2
Test Insert    Web Site    2
Test Insert    Web Site    2
Test Insert    Web Site    2
Test Insert    Web Site    2
test     Phone    2
test     Phone    2
test     Phone    2
Test Insert    Web Site    2
Test Insert    Email    2
```

Comment: What is your DBMS?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan MSSQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [CTE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14274942/sql-server-cte-and-recursion-example) to get your desired results. You can try below query:

```
;WITH ctePhone
    AS (
        SELECT DISTINCT ContactId           [ID],
        STUFF(( SELECT N', ' + Phone
            FROM Table1 B
             WHERE B.ContactId = A.ContactId
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                    ).value('(.)', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '') [Phone],
        STUFF(( SELECT N', ' + Email
            FROM Table1 B
             WHERE B.ContactId = A.ContactId
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                    ).value('(.)', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '') [Email],
        STUFF(( SELECT N', ' + Fax
            FROM Table1 B
             WHERE B.ContactId = A.ContactId
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                    ).value('(.)', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '') [Fax]
            FROM Table1 A
    )
SELECT DISTINCT #Table1.ContactId,
    ctePhone.Phone,
    ctePhone.Email,
    ctePhone.Fax
FROM Table1
    INNER JOIN ctePhone
        ON Table1.ContactId = ctePhone.[ID]
```

Answer (score 1):

if your DB's version is 2017+,you can use `string_agg()` function

```
select ContactId,
       string_agg(phone,',') within group (order by phone) as phone,
       string_agg(email,',') within group (order by email) as email,
       string_agg(fax,',') within group (order by fax) as fax
  from tab
 group by ContactId
```