# SQL repeat CTE for multiple values

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression, recursive-query

My problem is that I have this functional CTE statement in SQL. It works like a charm to find the deep hierarchy for my agency with id = 13.

Now what I want it to do is give me a result for multiple Ids (more specific all my leaves in the tree).

The statement for finding all the leaves are stated below the CTE.

Can this be done? Or do I need to run the query from code for each ID?

```
WITH parents AS (
  SELECT id, name, parent_id,  0 AS relative_depth
  FROM agencies
  where id = 13

  UNION ALL

  SELECT cat.id, cat.name, cat.parent_id, p.relative_depth - 1
  FROM agencies cat, parents p
  WHERE cat.id = p.parent_id
)
SELECT parents.id, parents.name as agency, parents.relative_depth FROM parents
```

Example Output with id=13:

```
id   name   relative_depth
13   D       0
12   C      -1
8    B      -2
2    A      -3
```

Example Output with id=11:

```
id   name   relative_depth
11   E      0
2    A      -1
```

So for the 4 leaves that i have from the below statement...

Leaves statement:

```
SELECT id
FROM   agencies t
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM   agencies
                   WHERE  parent_id = t.id)
```

I want to get a result like this:

```
leaf   id   name   relative_depth
 13    13   D       0
 13    12   C      -1
 13     8   B      -2
 13     2   A      -3
 11    11   E       0
 11     2   A      -2
  .     .   .       .
  .     .   .       .
```

/Kind regards

Comment: See [SQL Server CTE and recursion example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14274942/sql-server-cte-and-recursion-example).

Comment: please post some sample input and expected output..

Comment: If you want all ID's, why not just remove `where id = 2`? Also, come join the rest of us in 1992 onwards: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: Larnu: removing 'where id = 2' will not give me the hierarchical relations for each leaf node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does something like this work for you, where you would hold the top-level `id` in the `leaf` field, and then specify the `leaf` criteria in your final `SELECT`:

```
WITH parents AS (
  SELECT id leaf, id, name, parent_id,  0 AS relative_depth
  FROM agencies

  UNION ALL

  SELECT p.leaf, cat.id, cat.name, cat.parent_id, p.relative_depth - 1
  FROM agencies cat, parents p
  WHERE cat.id = p.parent_id
)

SELECT leaf, parents.id, parents.name as agency, parents.relative_depth
FROM parents
WHERE leaf IN (11, 13)
```

Comment: Thx! And i can then add the leaf select as inner select in the in () part

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't this work ?

```
WITH parents AS (
  SELECT id, name, parent_id,  0 AS relative_depth
  FROM agencies
  where parent_id is null

  UNION ALL

  SELECT cat.id, cat.name, cat.parent_id, p.relative_depth - 1
  FROM agencies cat, parents p
  WHERE cat.id = p.parent_id
)
SELECT parents.id, parents.name as agency, parents.relative_depth FROM parents
```

I use as the seed of the recursive CTE all the roots on your tree (the nodes with no parents), so you should arrive to all the leaves.