# How to get list of all levels of employees working under supervisor?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I need to get the list of employees down to the minimum level working under a specific supervisor or head or manager.

Below is the hierarchy of employees, each employee has a supervisor, who reports to a head and who reports to a manager as below:

[image: Employee_Hierarchy]

The data in the table has only 2 fields as follows:

[image]

My SQL Query would be `SELECT Employee_ID FROM DATABASE_TABLE WHERE Supervisor_ID='Joe'`. The result would be that I get the list of all employees reporting to `Joe` to the minimum level. Similarly, if I query for `Supervisor_ID='David'`, I should get all employees reporting to `David` to the minimum level.

I had experience in Oracle in this type of query by using `CONNECT_BY_PATH`, but I have no idea on how to achieve this in MS SQL. An example would be highly appreciable. Thanks.

> Create Table and Insert Statements:

```
CREATE TABLE DATABASE_TABLE(Employee_ID varchar(255),Supervisor_ID varchar(255));

INSERT INTO DATABASE_TABLE(Employee_ID, Supervisor_ID) VALUES ('Alice','Dave');
INSERT INTO DATABASE_TABLE(Employee_ID, Supervisor_ID) VALUES ('Olive','Dave');
INSERT INTO DATABASE_TABLE(Employee_ID, Supervisor_ID) VALUES ('Barton','Dave');
INSERT INTO DATABASE_TABLE(Employee_ID, Supervisor_ID) VALUES ('Almira','Jacob');
INSERT INTO DATABASE_TABLE(Employee_ID, Supervisor_ID) VALUES ('Charles','Jacob');
INSERT INTO DATABASE_TABLE(Employee_ID, Supervisor_ID) VALUES ('Davis','Jacob');
INSERT INTO DATABASE_TABLE(Employee_ID, Supervisor_ID) VALUES ('Robert','Risha');
INSERT INTO DATABASE_TABLE(Employee_ID, Supervisor_ID) VALUES ('Peter','Risha');
INSERT INTO DATABASE_TABLE(Employee_ID, Supervisor_ID) VALUES ('Ethel','Risha');
INSERT INTO DATABASE_TABLE(Employee_ID, Supervisor_ID) VALUES ('Isaac','Jospeh');
INSERT INTO DATABASE_TABLE(Employee_ID, Supervisor_ID) VALUES ('Sophia','Jospeh');
INSERT INTO DATABASE_TABLE(Employee_ID, Supervisor_ID) VALUES ('Rosa','Jospeh');
INSERT INTO DATABASE_TABLE(Employee_ID, Supervisor_ID) VALUES ('Joshua','Dandy');
INSERT INTO DATABASE_TABLE(Employee_ID, Supervisor_ID) VALUES ('Silas','Dandy');
INSERT INTO DATABASE_TABLE(Employee_ID, Supervisor_ID) VALUES ('Fred','Dandy');
INSERT INTO DATABASE_TABLE(Employee_ID, Supervisor_ID) VALUES ('Frank','Andrew');
INSERT INTO DATABASE_TABLE(Employee_ID, Supervisor_ID) VALUES ('Howard','Andrew');
INSERT INTO DATABASE_TABLE(Employee_ID, Supervisor_ID) VALUES ('Ralph','Andrew');
INSERT INTO DATABASE_TABLE(Employee_ID, Supervisor_ID) VALUES ('Dennis','Henry');
INSERT INTO DATABASE_TABLE(Employee_ID, Supervisor_ID) VALUES ('Alex','Henry');
INSERT INTO DATABASE_TABLE(Employee_ID, Supervisor_ID) VALUES ('Floyd','Henry');
INSERT INTO DATABASE_TABLE(Employee_ID, Supervisor_ID) VALUES ('Carlos','Nelson');
INSERT INTO DATABASE_TABLE(Employee_ID, Supervisor_ID) VALUES ('Homer','Nelson');
INSERT INTO DATABASE_TABLE(Employee_ID, Supervisor_ID) VALUES ('Harold','Nelson');
INSERT INTO DATABASE_TABLE(Employee_ID, Supervisor_ID) VALUES ('Leo','Simon');
INSERT INTO DATABASE_TABLE(Employee_ID, Supervisor_ID) VALUES ('Warren','Simon');
INSERT INTO DATABASE_TABLE(Employee_ID, Supervisor_ID) VALUES ('Clifford','Simon');
INSERT INTO DATABASE_TABLE(Employee_ID, Supervisor_ID) VALUES ('Martha','Casper');
INSERT INTO DATABASE_TABLE(Employee_ID, Supervisor_ID) VALUES ('Hazel','Casper');
INSERT INTO DATABASE_TABLE(Employee_ID, Supervisor_ID) VALUES ('Irene','Casper');
INSERT INTO DATABASE_TABLE(Employee_ID, Supervisor_ID) VALUES ('Dave','Betsy');
INSERT INTO DATABASE_TABLE(Employee_ID, Supervisor_ID) VALUES ('Jacob','Betsy');
INSERT INTO DATABASE_TABLE(Employee_ID, Supervisor_ID) VALUES ('Risha','David');
INSERT INTO DATABASE_TABLE(Employee_ID, Supervisor_ID) VALUES ('Jospeh','David');
INSERT INTO DATABASE_TABLE(Employee_ID, Supervisor_ID) VALUES ('Dandy','Phillip');
INSERT INTO DATABASE_TABLE(Employee_ID, Supervisor_ID) VALUES ('Andrew','Phillip');
INSERT INTO DATABASE_TABLE(Employee_ID, Supervisor_ID) VALUES ('Henry','Harvey');
INSERT INTO DATABASE_TABLE(Employee_ID, Supervisor_ID) VALUES ('Nelson','Harvey');
INSERT INTO DATABASE_TABLE(Employee_ID, Supervisor_ID) VALUES ('Simon','Paul');
INSERT INTO DATABASE_TABLE(Employee_ID, Supervisor_ID) VALUES ('Casper','Paul');
INSERT INTO DATABASE_TABLE(Employee_ID, Supervisor_ID) VALUES ('Betsy','Joe');
INSERT INTO DATABASE_TABLE(Employee_ID, Supervisor_ID) VALUES ('David','Joe');
INSERT INTO DATABASE_TABLE(Employee_ID, Supervisor_ID) VALUES ('Phillip','Joe');
INSERT INTO DATABASE_TABLE(Employee_ID, Supervisor_ID) VALUES ('Harvey','Joe');
INSERT INTO DATABASE_TABLE(Employee_ID, Supervisor_ID) VALUES ('Paul','Joe');
```

Comment: Images of data are useless to those you are asking for help from. Supply data as tabular formatted `text` or DDL and DML statements. Don't ask the users to transcribe it all; we won't. Why have you tagged 3 different versions of SQL Server? 2008 and 2008 are **completely** unsupported and 2012 only has extended support. What version are you *actually* using? Please edit your tag and only tag *that* version.

Comment: this post on cte recursion should help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14274942/sql-server-cte-and-recursion-example

Comment: Maybe it's just me. But when I see a column that ends with `Id`, then I would expect that it contains integers or guids.  With the names contained in referenced table(s) (f.e. T_Employees, T_Supervisors).

Comment: @lukStorms `Id` was used for representation purpose only.

Comment: Ok, makes sense.  Btw, both sql server and oracle db support Recursive CTE's.  Which can be used to traverse through an adjecency list like your table.  Check that link from JoeDBA_HAHAHA for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example that will give you some inspiration about how a recursive CTE can be used for this.

**Sample data:**

> ```
> CREATE TABLE DATABASE_TABLE 
> (
>   Employee_Name nvarchar(255) PRIMARY KEY,
>   Supervisor_Name nvarchar(255) NOT NULL
> );
>
> CREATE INDEX [ix_database_table_supervisor]
>     ON DATABASE_TABLE (Supervisor_Name);
> GO
>
> INSERT INTO DATABASE_TABLE
> (Employee_Name, Supervisor_Name) VALUES 
>   ('Alice','Dave')
> , ('Olive','Dave')
> , ('Barton','Dave')
> , ('Almira','Jacob')
> , ('Charles','Jacob')
> , ('Davis','Jacob')
> , ('Robert','Risha')
> , ('Peter','Risha')
> , ('Ethel','Risha')
> , ('Isaac','Jospeh')
> , ('Sophia','Jospeh')
> , ('Rosa','Jospeh')
> , ('Joshua','Dandy')
> , ('Silas','Dandy')
> , ('Fred','Dandy')
> , ('Frank','Andrew')
> , ('Howard','Andrew')
> , ('Ralph','Andrew')
> , ('Dennis','Henry')
> , ('Alex','Henry')
> , ('Floyd','Henry')
> , ('Carlos','Nelson')
> , ('Homer','Nelson')
> , ('Harold','Nelson')
> , ('Leo','Simon')
> , ('Warren','Simon')
> , ('Clifford','Simon')
> , ('Martha','Casper')
> , ('Hazel','Casper')
> , ('Irene','Casper')
> , ('Dave','Betsy')
> , ('Jacob','Betsy')
> , ('Risha','David')
> , ('Jospeh','David')
> , ('Dandy','Phillip')
> , ('Andrew','Phillip')
> , ('Henry','Harvey')
> , ('Nelson','Harvey')
> , ('Simon','Paul')
> , ('Casper','Paul')
> , ('Betsy','Joe')
> , ('David','Joe')
> , ('Phillip','Joe')
> , ('Harvey','Joe')
> , ('Paul','Joe')
> ```

**Query:**

> ```
> DECLARE @HeadName nvarchar(255);
> SET @HeadName = 'David';
>
> DECLARE @MaxLvl INT = 2;
>
>
> WITH RCTE_DATA AS
> (
>    -- seeding the recursion
>    SELECT
>    t.Employee_Name AS Head_Name,
>    t.Supervisor_Name AS Manager_Name,
>    0 AS Lvl,
>    t.Employee_Name, 
>    t.Supervisor_Name
>    FROM DATABASE_TABLE t
>    WHERE t.Employee_Name = @HeadName
>
>    UNION ALL
>
>    -- looping the recursion  
>    SELECT 
>    c.Head_Name,
>    c.Manager_Name,
>    c.Lvl + 1,
>    t.Employee_Name, 
>    t.Supervisor_Name
>    FROM RCTE_DATA c
>    JOIN DATABASE_TABLE t
>      ON t.Supervisor_Name = c.Employee_Name
>    WHERE c.Lvl < @MaxLvl
> )
> SELECT 
> Employee_Name, 
> Supervisor_Name, 
> Head_Name,
> Manager_Name
> FROM RCTE_DATA
> WHERE Lvl = @MaxLvl
> ```

**Results:**

> ```
> Employee_Name | Supervisor_Name | Head_Name | Manager_Name
> :------------ | :-------------- | :-------- | :-----------
> Ethel         | Risha           | David     | Joe         
> Peter         | Risha           | David     | Joe         
> Robert        | Risha           | David     | Joe         
> Isaac         | Jospeh          | David     | Joe         
> Rosa          | Jospeh          | David     | Joe         
> Sophia        | Jospeh          | David     | Joe
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=c82fcfa6047826a4f3d504bac0d73504)*

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from  (

SELECT a.Employee_Name, a.Supervisor_Name, b.Supervisor_Name as Head_Name,  c.Supervisor_Name as Manager_Name
FROM DATABASE_TABLE a
LEFT JOIN DATABASE_TABLE b ON a.Supervisor_Name = b.Employee_Name
LEFT JOIN DATABASE_TABLE c ON b.Supervisor_Name = c.Employee_Name) as t

where t.Head_Name='David'
order by Supervisor_Name ;
```