Truncate path into descending subpaths
I have a path that looks like this
Subdomain1>Subdomain2>Subdomain3>Subdomain3>Subdomain5

The length is variable, and it is possible that it could be NULL as well.
How could I create 5 columns such that
Column 1 shows the root, column 2 shows the root and the next node, etc
So column 3 would be Subdomain1>Subdomain2>Subdomain3 in this case
If the path was
Subdomain1>Subdomain2

Then the column 3, 4 and 4 would be null
and of the path was
Subdomain1>Subdomain2>Subdomain3>Subdomain3>Subdomain5>Subdomain6

then column 5 would be  Subdomain1>Subdomain2>Subdomain3>Subdomain3>Subdomain5
We are running SQL Server 2016

I would look more into a parent/child type relationship in the single table so each relationship would have 5 rows in the table but you could have as many parent/child relationships as you wanted.  Then use recursion query to find the full path, something similar to this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14274942/sql-server-cte-and-recursion-example

What research have you done? What have you tried and got stuck on?

While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements.
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

You could use CTE to split path into parts. Then you can pivot data based on level of subpath.

Just saying, if you are looking to aggregate hierarchical data, there are better methods.

Have you even tried anything???

Please try the following solution based on tokenization and leveraging SQL Server XML and XQuery functionality.
Notable points:

1st CROSS APPLY is converting path to XML.
2nd CROSS APPLY is counting number of tokens in the path.
Calculated col1 - col5 columns are using XQuery .query() method to
get path's subset that is matching column#.
Logic based on IIF() function gets us NULL value for appropriate
columns.

SQL
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, _path VARCHAR(256));
INSERT INTO @tbl (_path) VALUES
('Subdomain1>Subdomain2>Subdomain3>Subdomain3>Subdomain5'),
('Subdomain1>Subdomain2');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = '>';

SELECT *
    , col1 = IIF(cnt < 1, NULL, REPLACE(c.query('data(/root/r[position() le 1])')
        .value('.', 'VARCHAR(256)'),SPACE(1),@separator))
    , col2 = IIF(cnt < 2, NULL, REPLACE(c.query('data(/root/r[position() le 2])')
        .value('.', 'VARCHAR(256)'),SPACE(1),@separator))
    , col3 = IIF(cnt < 3, NULL, REPLACE(c.query('data(/root/r[position() le 3])')
        .value('.', 'VARCHAR(256)'),SPACE(1),@separator))
    , col4 = IIF(cnt < 4, NULL, REPLACE(c.query('data(/root/r[position() le 4])') 
        .value('.', 'VARCHAR(256)'),SPACE(1),@separator))
    , col5 = IIF(cnt < 5, NULL, REPLACE(c.query('data(/root/r[position() le 5])') 
        .value('.', 'VARCHAR(256)'),SPACE(1),@separator))
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
      REPLACE(_path, @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
      ']]></r></root>' AS XML)) AS t1(c)
CROSS APPLY (SELECT c.value('count(/root/r)', 'INT')) AS t2(cnt);

Output



id
_path
col1
col2
col3
col4
col5




1
Subdomain1>Subdomain2>Subdomain3>Subdomain3>Subdomain5
Subdomain1
Subdomain1>Subdomain2
Subdomain1>Subdomain2>Subdomain3
Subdomain1>Subdomain2>Subdomain3>Subdomain3
Subdomain1>Subdomain2>Subdomain3>Subdomain3>Subdomain5


2
Subdomain1>Subdomain2
Subdomain1
Subdomain1>Subdomain2
NULL
NULL
NULL




Just another option using JSON
Declare @YourTable Table ([Path] varchar(150))  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
         ('Subdomain1>Subdomain2>Subdomain3>Subdomain3>Subdomain5')
        ,('Subdomain1>Subdomain2')

     
Select Col1 = Pos1
      ,Col2 = Pos1+'>'+Pos2
      ,Col3 = Pos1+'>'+Pos2+'>'+Pos3
      ,Col4 = Pos1+'>'+Pos2+'>'+Pos3+'>'+Pos4
      ,Col5 = Pos1+'>'+Pos2+'>'+Pos3+'>'+Pos4+'>'+Pos5
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (Select Pos1 = JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[0]')
                    ,Pos2 = JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[1]')
                    ,Pos3 = JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[2]')
                    ,Pos4 = JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[3]')
                    ,Pos5 = JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[4]')
              From (values ('["'+replace(string_escape([Path],'json'),'>','","')+'"]') ) B1(JS)) B

Results
Col1        Col2                    Col3                                Col4                                        Col5
Subdomain1  Subdomain2>Subdomain2   Subdomain2>Subdomain2>Subdomain3    Subdomain2>Subdomain2>Subdomain3>Subdomain3 Subdomain2>Subdomain2>Subdomain3>Subdomain3>Subdomain5
Subdomain1  Subdomain2>Subdomain2   NULL                                NULL                                        NULL


Smart usage of concatenation with nulls.

Using more traditional string parsing techniques, you can use a series of CROSS APPLYs to calculate successive delimiter positions
and then use the LEFT() function to extract each leading portion.
SELECT
    D.Id, D.Path,
    LEFT(D.Path, P1.Pos - 1) AS Level1,
    LEFT(D.Path, P2.Pos - 1) AS Level2,
    LEFT(D.Path, P3.Pos - 1) AS Level3,
    LEFT(D.Path, P4.Pos - 1) AS Level4,
    LEFT(D.Path, P5.Pos - 1) AS Level5
FROM Data D
CROSS APPLY(SELECT Path + '>' AS ExtPath) EP -- It's easier with an extra delimiter
CROSS APPLY(SELECT NULLIF(CHARINDEX('>', EP.ExtPath            ), 0) AS Pos) P1
CROSS APPLY(SELECT NULLIF(CHARINDEX('>', EP.ExtPath, P1.Pos + 1), 0) AS Pos) P2
CROSS APPLY(SELECT NULLIF(CHARINDEX('>', EP.ExtPath, P2.Pos + 1), 0) AS Pos) P3
CROSS APPLY(SELECT NULLIF(CHARINDEX('>', EP.ExtPath, P3.Pos + 1), 0) AS Pos) P4
CROSS APPLY(SELECT NULLIF(CHARINDEX('>', EP.ExtPath, P4.Pos + 1), 0) AS Pos) P5
ORDER BY D.Id

The NULLIF() function is used above to map the no-match CHARINDEX() result from zero to null, which just works better with this logic.
This could also be converted to use a recursive CTE followed by a PIVOT, but another answer has already demonstrated that.
Results (with some modified test data):



Id
Path
Level1
Level2
Level3
Level4
Level5




1
S1>S2>S3>S4>S5>S6
S1
S1>S2
S1>S2>S3
S1>S2>S3>S4
S1>S2>S3>S4>S5


2
One>Two>Three
One
One>Two
One>Two>Three
null
null


3
A>B>C>D>E>F>G>H
A
A>B
A>B>C
A>B>C>D
A>B>C>D>E


4
Single
Single
null
null
null
null


5


null
null
null
null


6
>>

>
>>
null
null


7
null
null
null
null
null
null



See this db<>fiddle for a demo.

Another way is to use CTE and PIVOT.
Table creation:
CREATE TABLE MyPaths(id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, aPath VARCHAR(256));
INSERT INTO MyPaths (apath) VALUES
('Subdomain1>Subdomain2>Subdomain3>Subdomain4>Subdomain5'),
('Subdomain1>Subdomain2');

Query:
DECLARE @sep CHAR(1) = '>';

;WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT id, aPath, LEFT(aPath, CHARINDEX(@sep, aPath)-1) PartOfPath, 
    RIGHT(aPath, LEN(aPath) - CHARINDEX(@sep, aPath)) RemainingPath, 1 Lvl
  FROM MyPaths
  WHERE CHARINDEX(@sep, aPath) > 0
  UNION ALL
  SELECT id, aPath, LEFT(RemainingPath, CHARINDEX(@sep, RemainingPath)-1) PartOfPath, 
    RIGHT(RemainingPath, LEN(RemainingPath) - CHARINDEX(@sep, RemainingPath)) RemainingPath, 
    Lvl + 1
  FROM CTE
  WHERE CHARINDEX(@sep, RemainingPath) > 0
  UNION ALL
  SELECT id, aPath, RemainingPath PartOfPath, 
    NULL RemainingPath, Lvl + 1
  FROM CTE
  WHERE CHARINDEX(@sep, RemainingPath) = 0
)
SELECT id, aPath, [1], [2], [3], [4], [5]
FROM
(
  SELECT id, aPath, PartOfPath, Lvl
  FROM CTE
) Src
PIVOT(MAX(PartOfPath) FOR Lvl IN([1], [2], [3], [4], [5])) Pvt
ORDER BY id;

SqlFiddle
